# Overriding Spring definition: Spring Bean Annotation @Primary

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Overriding a bean definition appears to me be harder than what I thought.
First of all,  I would like to keep Open/Close principle.

I am using Springfox that would provide a swagger json based on Spring Mapping. Springfox is loaded by a Config class that I have to provide:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import({Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"special.package.swagger"})
public class ApplicationSwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("rest-api")
                .select()
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/rest-api");
    }
   ...
```

Of course, I don't wanna change Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration class (following the open/closed principle) but change the behavior of  ServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper.

For that, I created a  MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper class in "special.package.swagger" folder such as:

```
@Component
@Primary
public class MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper extends ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl {

    @Override
    public Swagger mapDocumentation(Documentation from) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n******************** Override works!!!\n");
        return super.mapDocumentation(from);
    }

}
```

Spring loads the component, what solves the ambiguity problem but at the override does not work. Does anyone has any idea why!?

---

Edit:  @smarquis comments helped a lot. Spring is working properly.

I accidentally added multiple versions of springfox library. The application server loaded both libraries and got lost. Once the classpath issue was solved overriding worked perfectly.

Comment: Are you sure that `@Primary` is working and the it is loading your custom defined bean?

Comment: If you implement `BeanNameAware` in`MyServiceModelTowagger2Mapper`, what is the value of the first argument of the parameter from the inherited method `setBeanName(Str)`?

Comment: @user2004685, Primary annotation is working properly. Without that,  I got ambiguity exception. Using it, I can see the bean getting initialized.

Comment: @PeterRader, MyServiceModelTowagger2Mapper does not implement BeanNameAware.

Comment: @rdllopes And if you implement `BeanNameAware`? What is the value of the first argument of the parameter from the inherited method `setBeanName(str)`?

Comment: it does not matter, right!? Is your suggestion is using the same name as the previous bean i.e. "serviceModelTowagger2Mapper"? in that case, I will check it tomorrow and answer you.

Comment: @PeterRader, the result was...
org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'serviceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl' for bean class 
[springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.ServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [special.package.swagger.MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the way spring with java config is build -- it is getting quite complex internally with proxies and stuff.

I do not remember exactly the reason, but if you do it like this your override works:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import({Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration.class})
//@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"springfoxswagger.specialpackageswagger"})
public class ApplicationSwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("rest-api")
                .select()
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/rest-api");
    }


    @Bean
    public springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.ServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper mapper() {
        return new  ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl() {
            public Swagger mapDocumentation(Documentation from) {
                System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n******************** Override works!!!\n");
                return super.mapDocumentation(from);
            }

        };
    }

}
```

It is also simpler, arguably.

**EDIT**

It seems not to work for the OP, so I investigated a bit further.

- If you just add the second implementation of ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl without @Primary, you get the exception "...expected single matching bean but found 2"
- If you add it with the annotation, you get what the OP says (spring starts, but the override does not work).
- if you again add the @Bean in my solution, that makes **three** implementations of ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl, and without any @Primary at all, spring starts and the override works.
- Note that you do not need the @Primary annotation on the bean, wierdly enough.

  ```
  2016-01-26 08:50:26.594  INFO 58548 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 22 ms
  ```

  ******************** Override works!!!
- "Simple" solutions like adding @BeanNameAware or @AnnotationConfigDriven will not do. IMO OP bumped into a Spring Java Config bug or limitation; I do not see any reason why his solution does not work.

Comment: That was indeed my first solution  and it was not working. Spring was not invoking mapper() method at all.

Comment: Interesting; I have implemented here now to make sure and it does work:

2016-01-26 08:12:34.724  INFO 58405 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-01-26 08:12:34.745  INFO 58405 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms













******************** Override works!!!

Comment: Which version are you using? Mine is Spring 3.2.

Comment: Solved!  The problem was multiple versions of springfox library. So, Spring is not guilty. The application server loaded both libraries and got lost. One the classpath was solved override worked perfectly.  I am adding this comment in the question. very good job @smarquis.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` on your class and try this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@AnnotationDrivenConfig
@Import({Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration.class})
public class ApplicationSwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .groupName("rest-api")
                .select()
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/rest-api");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper mapper() {
        return new MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper();
    }
}
```

MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper Class:

```
public class MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper extends ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl {

    @Override
    public Swagger mapDocumentation(Documentation from) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n******************** Override works!!!\n");
        return super.mapDocumentation(from);
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing that is not so good in that solution is that ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl has lot of dependencies. Springfox solution is autowired those dependencies. So, initialize MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper  would require to access all dependencies.

Comment: Another problem. I don't have that class "AnnotationDrivenConfig" in my classpath. I am using Spring 3.2.

Comment: `@AnnotationDrivenConfig` is just to enable the `@Autowired` and other annotations and it is available in Spring 3.2. And sorry I didn't understand your earlier comment. I just replaced the Component Scanning part with `@Bean` in the proposed solution.

Comment: About the first comment. 
new MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper(); <= would not wire dependencies. // the Javaconfig way would be new MyServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper(dep1, dep2, dep3, dep4, and_so_on);

Comment: About the second comment. I cannot find AnnotationDrivenConfig  in standard Spring framework: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/.

Comment: I finished all tests... AnnotationDrivenConfig is not really needed. It would allow normal component objects. For now, we just need spring mvc and rest annotations.